# How to Ignore all folders with folder pattern using prettier

Tags: prettier, nsregularexpression, prettier-eslint

When I execute the following command in a root folder of a project, all the files recursively get run as I expect.

prettier --write "**/*.{js,ts}"

However, I want to ignore all folders that start with ./next or ./old in those subfolders. How can I do that? I've tried the commands below but they don't ignore those folders

prettier --write "**/*.{js,ts}" --ignore-path ".next"

prettier --write "**/*.{js,ts}" --ignore-path "**/.next"

Answer (score 4):

You can add `.next` or `/.next` to the `.prettierignore` file.

-- ignore-path is `the path to a file containing patterns that describe files to ignore`; It's not the folder to be ignored!!

Kindly read [this](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html#--ignore-path)